# Windows 8 slowly becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-8, ssd, freeze

A couple of months ago my PC randomly started freezing. By this I mean one program after another would stop responding, yet others would work. Frequently, but by no means exclusively, this happened during a Visual Studio build of even a simple project. But it also occurred when VS had never been run since a reboot - I think it was just good at provoking whatever was causing a freeze. Even Ctrl+Alt+Del to get Task Manager would fail; indeed no icons on the task bar would launch anything. Firefox would either hang completely or be responsive but fail to load any pages (but without timing out). The only solution would be to hold down the power button on the PC to kill it.

I have tried all manner of suggestions: defrag (though my system drive is an SSD), have 68gig free out of 223gig on that drive, have uninstalled as much as possible, don't have any crappy IE toolbars or "helpers", use CCleaner, have examined the event log (nothing obvious), have run deep virus scans (BitDefender paid version), ran Malbytes Antimalware, left Task Manager open before a freeze to see if anything was hogging after a freeze (nope), have plenty of memory (25% of 8gig used), have no context menu helpers, don't have any more than the bare minimum of startup programs (eg Adobe Updaters disabled), checked all drivers (up to date), checked firmware for the SSD (up to date), have run memory scanners outside of Windows, disk checkers, have nothing in the recycle bin, used Kingston's tool box to check the SSD (a-ok), unplugged unnecessary USB devices (except keyboard and mouse), Googled and looked at scores of "solutions", and probably tried some witchcraft too.

A couple of weeks after the above mysteriously started, it just as mysteriously stopped. It was fine for the next several weeks. But since yesterday, I've now had to do probably a dozen reboots. Same symptoms as last time. Even though Firefox would hang, I noticed that while the computer is falling into a meltdown situation, if Thunderbird and Skype were open, both would function relatively normally - even voice calls on Skype.

But I can't help thinking it's something to do with drives. I was moving a whole bunch of stuff from one drive to another today and though the files were transferring okay, anything else that needed that drive would hang - sometimes interminably, sometimes eventually "un"hanging. But other times not so. Again, all drives have been checked. I'm really running out of ideas now so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It does sounds like your HDD (SSD) issue... do you have a different drive you can test with? Or you can try (which unfortunately in this case purchase, and if you're not happy, get a refund within 30 days) SpinRite by grc.com. I'm not affiliated with him in anyway, but I did use his software (and read many testimonials) and I can vouch that his software can do some difference, especially if this is truly caused by data issue on the SSD/HDD. I've had HDD that tested fine on SpinRite, but after the test, the HDD loads up faster, so in a way similar to your condition (except you have SSD).

Comment: post pictures of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html. Also post more details about your used hardware.

Comment: I had a similar problem for a while. Windows got slower and slower. Turned out be be a failing disk (Smart errors "Reallocated Sector Count" on the c: drive). Now I have a new drive :/ Might be time to check yours ... [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?]() ... most of the utilities mentioned in that question will probably run on windows 8 as well.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go away and it's my main PC at home which I can't get to at the moment. Before I went away I installed a new HDD and unplugged the SSD and... boom, Windows still locked up. I will get back onto this when I get back.